# Make a menu item behave like a button

Tags: asp.net, button, menuitem, menubar

Is it possible to make a menu item behave like a button? By this I mean that instead of setting the NavigateUrl property to a new page, assign a method when the item is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a click handler for the menu.
The [MenuItemClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick.aspx) tells you which item was clicked.

```
<asp:menu id="NavigationMenu"
        onmenuitemclick="NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick" 
        runat="server">
```

You could take action depending upon which item was clicked by the user.

```
  void NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick(Object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Item.Text == "MyItem")
    {
      //do some processing
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can do it..you can call a server side function using`__dopostback()` for example
on your menu item's click you can call this `Javascipt function`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SaveWithParameter(parameter)
{
  __doPostBack('btnSave ', parameter)
}
</script>
```

Comment: what about without using javascript?

Comment: Then you need to add server controls in your menu items instead of `HTML` elements...and as everyone knows..each server control has postback methods..

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
<asp:menuitem navigateurl="javascript:YourJScript()"
```

If you need to execute a method in serverside, use a hidden variable, then set a flag in javascript method and submit the page.

In serverside, check the flag in page load and call the method as required.

Thanks